# How to make HTTP requests from Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to make HTTP requests from Firefox extension, so I decided to use third-party libraries [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) for this purpose.

Unfortunately, when I import them via the following statements

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
```

it give me the following error when I run it via `jpm run`:

> console.error: forwardme:   Message: Module `net` is not found at
>   resource://gre/modules/commonjs/net.js   Stack:
>       @resource://forwardme/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js:32:11
>   @resource://forwardme/node_modules/request/lib/cookies.js:3:13
>   @resource://forwardme/node_modules/request/index.js:18:29
>   @resource://forwardme/index.js:21:15
>   run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:145:19
>   startup/

Why? What am I doing wrong?

What is the easiest way to make HTTP GET and POST requests from Firefox addon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core node modules are not available in SDK because it's not actually a node environment.

I recommend you browse [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) to see available APIs like [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request).

Alternatively, you can make use of the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which is the new kid on the block everyone is talking about these days. This of course needs a reference to a `window` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how can I parse a result of HTTP request (HTML body)?

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser