# Firefox Addon error: Module `http` is not found

Tags: node.js, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a Firefox Addon and attempting to use the DBPedia Spotlight package which depends on the http package.

When I put the line

```
var http = require('http');
```

or

```
var mlspotlight = require('dbpedia-spotlight');
```

at the top of the index.js file, I get the error:

```
Module `http` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/http.js
```

I have tried to install the http package using

```
npm install http --save
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977073/firefox-addon-error-module-path-is-not-found-at-resource-gre-modules-common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core node modules are not available in the Addon SDK.
More info on this question: [How to make HTTP requests from Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724844/how-to-make-http-requests-from-firefox-extension)